# Error in installing DevKit

Tags: ruby, devkit

Getting this error while installing DevKit

```
C:\DevKit>gem install json --platform=ruby  
Fetching: json-1.7.7.gem (100%)  
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...  
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...  
Successfully installed json-1.7.7  
Parsing documentation for json-1.7.7  
unable to convert "\x90" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/json/ext/generator.so,  
 skipping   
unable to convert "\x90" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/json/ext/parser.so, sk  
ipping  
Installing ri documentation for json-1.7.7  
Done installing documentation for json (3 sec).  
1 gem installed
```

Can anybody help me out here.

Comment: They are warnings, not errors. 
Your gem seems to be installed. 
Did you tried to use the json gem?

Comment: The warnings are related to the documentation of json gem. The messages you sent shows no errors, so i think your installation is fine. Double check your DevKit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first install rdoc
using gem install rdoc

I was also facing same problem.